# Issue with viewpager toolbar height when keyboard opening in fragment

Tags: android, xml

[Code of Activity XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jomDm.png)
[image: See above tool bar]

original tool bar size:

[image: original tool bar size]

when keyboard opens , tool bar reduces in size. In main activity hierarchy of views is included toolbar >> Sliding tab layout >> view pager. Fragment layout is added to the view pager using adapter. Please help why tool bar height is reducing when keyboard is opening in fragment. TIA

Comment: try to add one flag android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in your activity manifest.

Comment: this is not working for me. @Abhishek

Comment: put your xml code for activity.

Comment: @Abhishek I have added the Code of Activity XML, please find link above. TIA

Comment: Can you add manifest file too

Comment: when I remove list view from the fragment layout xml, it will popup whole layout up when keyboard is opened. Is it not possible to add a scroll view in fragment layout with edit text? @AldrinMathew - what to do when there is no list view in fragment and only scroll view is there? How to stop poping up layout when keyboard is up? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here's what you should do.

Remove the layout weight for toolbar and give it fixed height.

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: thanks, is this will work good for all devices? I mean - fixed height will be good for all device screen sizes ? @Aldrin

Comment: yeah sure. Action bar size will be the mostly the same for all phones

Comment: Can you accept the answer and upvote it if you're satisfied please